# $A$ is a retract of $X$ iff the inclusion map $\iota $ has the left inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

> Let $A\subset X.$We say that **$A$** is a retract of **$X$** if there
>   exists a continuous map **$r:A\rightarrow X$** such that $r(a)=a
>  \forall a\in A$.The map $r$ is called the **retraction map**.

Now ,
If $\iota:A\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion map, then the condition $ r(a)=a,$ for all $a\in A$ is equivalent to saying that $r\circ \iota=I_{A}$.

How to conclude from the above two facts that-

> $A$ is a retract of $X$ iff the inclusion map $\iota $ has the left
>   inverse.?

Comment: $\iota$ has left inverse iff there exists $f:X \to A$ such that $f\circ \iota=I_A$. If you understand the sentence between highlighted sections, then you understand the conclusion, there is no way to explain it further.

Comment: You want to say $r: X \to A$, not $r: A \to X$. Maybe that's confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reformulation of the definition.

Suppose that $\iota: A \to X$ has a (continuous) left inverse, say $r: X \to A$ with $r \circ \iota = \textrm{id}_A$. Then for all $a \in A$: $$a= \textrm{id}_A(a) = (r \circ \iota)(a) = r(\iota(a)) = r(a)$$

so that $r$ is the identity on $A$. So $r$  is a retraction map according to the definition.

And if $r$ is a retraction, the same equations say again that $r$ is a left inverse.